# Jquery - Duplicate a button on the same div container, so I have 2 sets of buttons with the same functionality (above and below the container)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, duplicates, clone

I'm totally new to this, as I'm mainly a designer, so beware: I'm learning.
I'm trying to modify a WP plugin, to be able to clone a button via JQuery.
The original code is this:

```
    SliderBehaviour.prototype.setupButtons = function (container, buttons) {
            var _this = this;
            this.$buttons = buttons;
            this.$voteButton = this.$buttons.filter('button[value="vote"]');
            this.$resultsButton = this.$buttons.filter('button[value="results"]');
            this.$previousButton = jQuery("<button type=\"button\" class=\"totalpoll-button totalpoll-buttons-slider-previous\">" + this.poll.config['i18n']['Previous'] + "</button>");
            this.$nextButton = jQuery("<button type=\"button\" class=\"totalpoll-button totalpoll-buttons-slider-next\">" + this.poll.config['i18n']['Next'] + "</button>");                            
            container.prepend(this.$previousButton);
            container.append(this.$nextButton);
```

After much reading and checking and trying, I added this line: `container.append(this.$nextButton).clone(true, true).prependTo(".totalpoll-form");` after the last line of the previous code.

It does duplicate the buttons but they don't work. It actually shows all the buttons (previous, vote, next) instead of only showing "Next" as it does on the original set of buttons below the div.

So basically the buttons show and work below the container, I need a duplicate set of buttons ALSO on top of the container.

Buttons
Container
Buttons

I'm not sure if a code somewhere else on the plugin is preventing the buttons to work. I understood that using `clone (true, true)` would duplicate the element and its functionality. I'm confused and sorry if I'm too new to this and I might be asking for help on something totally easy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't set event listeners on the buttons, so when you clone it there are still no event listeners.  You would have to find where the event listeners are added and modify that code to also add them to your new cloned buttons.

Comment: oh we solved it differently in the end, but thanks to your input we found where to do the proper changes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can probably close this question now, if you figured it out :)